# Why does the following struct declaration in C++ causes exit 127?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, exit-code

I am trying to solve a problem on the USACO Training page and to solve it I figured I would need the following declaration:

```
const int NMAX=35;
.
.
.
struct type{
     int x,y;
     int mat[2][NMAX][NMAX];
};
```

Using this, I've written a program that works on my computer but when I send the source file to the USACO Grader I receive the following error:

> Your program printed data to stderr. Here is the data:
>   program:_error_while_loading_shared_libraries:_libm.so.6:_failed_to_map_segment_from_shared_object

Since I have no idea what it means, I sent more sources commenting chunks of code trying to narrow down what causes it and I noticed that the error is given at compilation time, before the program runs. More, I saw that if I comment the struct declaration the program manages to compile, and if I leave the struct not commented but I comment the three dimensional array declaration, it also compiles.

Example:

```
struct type{
     int x,y;
     //int mat[2][NMAX][NMAX]; 
};
```

(the above code is ok)

Could you please explain what is wrong with this declaration and how to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Edit: My initial belief was that the struct itself was the source of the error but the reality was that it was an array declaration following right after the struct declaration.

```
const int NMAX=35;
.
.
.
struct type{
     int x,y;
     int mat[2][NMAX][NMAX];
}arr[NMAX*NMAX];
```

Checking the constraints of the problem statement allowed me to slim down on the size of the array and it solved the issue. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Where do you use this struct?  To declare a local variable in a function?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including **complete** source code that causes the problem, pasted exactly, not retyped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a semicolon after the closing curly brace of the struct.

```
struct type{
 int x,y;
 int mat[2][NMAX][NMAX];
};  //  <-this semicolon
```

And that should do it.

Comment: There is a semicolon in the source code, it's just that I mistyped the code in the question, sorry.

Comment: I think I found the key. I'm trying to declare an array of that struct of length NMAX*NMAX. Perhaps it has no idea how to allocate that space? If I send the source with the initial struct declaration but without the array declaration it also works.

Comment: @PaulOrasan An NMAX*NMAX array of those structs is over 12 million bytes and is almost certainly too large for automatic storage (stack memory). You need to put that information in the question. Some real code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I've edited the question and found the solution to the issue. Since I'm new with stack overflow, should I mark it as solved somehow?

Comment: @PaulOrasan You could post your own answer and accept that. That's perfectly fine here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: as can be seen in the edited section of the question, the problem resided with the memory allocation of an array of that struct type and not the struct declaration itself and it had to do with the constraints of the problem.